# Adding background picture inside margin

Tags: html, image, notepad++, border, margin

I am a beginner in making html. I am only in high school.

We were tasked to make a website and I wanted for it to look like the picture below. We were only allowed to use notepad to create it, applications weren't allowed. (like Adobe Dreamweaver) I have trouble in putting a picture in the background (refer to image, the red part with an arrow). I also want to know how to insert a picture and how to wrap text around it. How can I pull this off in notepad?

Thanks in advance!

[HERE'S THE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0krv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
body  {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

replace the paper.gif with your own background image

Comment: sorry, this was not I was wanting... to clarify, the red part in the picture I have given is the area I wanted to place a picture in, not the entire thing... the green area will have another picture or a simple background color...

Comment: Hi Pot, Can you post your code, so that i can have a look.:)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.
By first, if you want ONE image to reach the red on the left AND the red on the right, you must do it:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
   <div class="greenDiv">
      And here goes the content of your webiste
   </div>
</div>
```

The css to put the image on the red(s):

```
.mainDiv {
  background-image: url("folder/file.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; //if you dont want it to be reppeated.
}
```

if you are not familiar with css, you can use it, inside the div `mainDiv`, like this: `<div class="mainDiv" style="background-image:url('folder/file.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>`

But, if you want to use one image for EACH red, you must separate them in two divs, like this:

```
<div class="leftRed" style="background-image:url('folder/img1.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
<div class="greenDiv"></div>
<div class="rightRed" style="background-image:url('folder/img2.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where do I place the 'div'? Can I insert it anywhere in the whole html?

Comment: the div should be inside your <body> tag.
like this:
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: This is how it looks like when I copy it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt7px0g8u15xsbn/%3Bikaj%2Csmnxfd.png?dl=0

Comment: Pick the code of one of examples i wrote above, put in a text editor (like notepad) and save document as .html (name.html). After this, when you reach the result as the example, we can go on on your website

Comment: Ok, now we are closer of what you desired, right?
put your code (the <h4> till <p>some info</p> <br>... inside the greenDiv tag.
after this, you can improve the size of greenDiv changing its values in width:400px; to some value you would like to have.. like 800px (example)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin, but you have a lot to learn (that's a good thing!). I cleaned up your code and put a `background-image` inside the `body` element as that's what you wanted to achieve.

```
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
```

Using `align="center` is deprecated. Do not use this to get valid markup. Please use the `<style>` in `<head>` to use `text-align: center;` or better to use [an external stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS). It's a reference to another file to add the styling to the `body` of the document.

You can find more info on *Getting started with CSS?* at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started).

```html
<html>

<head>
<title> My First HTML File</title>

<style type="text/css">

body { 
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg'); 
border: 30px solid red;
color: #fff; /*colour of text*/
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
font-style: normal;
font-family: Gisha, Verdana, Lucida Console, Helvetica;
font-size: 12pt;
}


</style>



</head>

<body>

<h4>Home Page</h4>
<hr>

<br>

<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="url" style="color:white"> Home</a> | 
<a href="url" style="text-decoration:none; color:white">About </a>| 
<a href="url" style="text-decoration:none; color:white">Portfolio</a> | 
<a href="url" style="text-decoration:none; color:white">Contact </a>
</p>



<br><br>
<h2  style="text-align: center;"> WELCOME to my website!</h2>


<p> some info </p>



<br>
<br>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Just one thing, the background image doesn't appear even if I have changed the link to the directory path....

Comment: @potpotpot Is it in the same folder as the rest of the files? What's the directory structure?

Comment: what other files are you talking about?

Comment: Is your image in the same document folder as the `index.html`?

Comment: It isn't... Should I place them in one folder?

Comment: I have placed them in to one folder (the .html files and the picture files) but still, nothing happened

Comment: What's the name *and filetype* of the image you want to use?

Comment: @potpotpot `background-image: url('IMG_0827.JPG');` should be added in the `<style>` section of the `<head>`.